# How can I add a variable to a regexp? (Perl)

Tags: perl

So here's my sample

```
while (<FH>) {

  my $line = $_;
  chomp($line);

  my $marksearchpat= "href=\"\@X\@EmbeddedFile\.requestUrlStub\@X\@bbcswebdav\/xid";      
  my $markreplacepat= "href=\"http:\/\/www\.facepalm\.org\/bbcswebdav\/xid";    
  ## (Mark)  Duplicate input file lines to "altered" file, making substitutions as necessary.
  $linenumber++;    
    print "Line $linenumber Has Been Read\n";
  my $line2=$_;    
  $line2=~s/$marksearchpat/$markreplacepat/eig;  
  print WHOUT $line2;     
  print WHLOG 'At '.localtime().', I replaced '. $marksearchpat .' with '. $markreplacepat .' at line '.$linenumber.' of file '.$file."\n";
```

How do I add a regex variable (A regex match variable)to the $marksearchpat and to the $markreplacepat

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything with

```
s/$search_pat/$replace/
```

since interpolation does not interpret the interpolated values at all. That's why you added `/e`.

```
s/$search_pat/$replace_code/e
```

In the above, the value of `$replace_code` is expected to Perl code. That to which the last expression in `$replace_code` evaluates will be the replacement string. So what Perl code would do that? Either of the following would do:

```
'http://www.facepalm.org/bbcswebdav/xid-' . $1

"http://www.facepalm.org/bbcswebdav/xid-$1"
```

To place that in `$replace_code`, we can use any of the following:

```
my $replace_code = '"http://www.facepalm.org/bbcswebdav/xid-$1"';
my $replace_code = q{"http://www.facepalm.org/bbcswebdav/xid-$1"};
my $replace_code = q{'http://www.facepalm.org/bbcswebdav/xid-' . $1};
etc
```

So we end up with:

```
my $search_re = qr{href="\K\@X\@EmbeddedFile\.requestUrlStub\@X\@bbcswebdav/xid-([0-9]{9}_2)};
my $replace_code = q{"http://www.facepalm.org/bbcswebdav/xid-$1"};
s/$search_re/$replace_code/gie;
```

Technically, don't need to capture anything by using a lookahead:

```
my $search_re = qr{href="\K\@X\@EmbeddedFile\.requestUrlStub\@X\@bbcswebdav/xid-(?=[0-9]{9}_2)};
my $replace_code = q{"http://www.facepalm.org/bbcswebdav/xid-"};
s/$search_re/$replace_code/gie;
```

Which also means we don't need `/e`:

```
my $search_re = qr{href="\K\@X\@EmbeddedFile\.requestUrlStub\@X\@bbcswebdav/xid-(?=[0-9]{9}_2)};
my $replace_str = 'http://www.facepalm.org/bbcswebdav/xid-'
s/$search_re/$replace_str/gi;
```

Comment: PS - I added a `\K` because you were accidentally replacing the `href="` too.

Comment: I have a  log that prints out  what changes will it show the change for the different variable or just the text that appears